# Is it possible to use binary logic in templates in short way?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I want do something for integral types but not chars and I have

`is_integral<T>::type` and `is_char<T>::type`

Is it possible to write this:

`integral_constant<bool,is::integral<T>::value && !is_char<T>::value>`

more readable

Comment: Yes, that's valid syntax. Is that your whole question?

Comment: @ildjarn I want to know if there is more elegant way

Comment: what could be any more elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those kinds of metacomputations were done even before C++11 and [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) is the heavy artillery of TMP in C++03. With it, your requirements can be expressed like so:

```
// in C++03:
// typedef /* compute */ result;
using result = and_<is_integral<T>, not_<is_char<T>>>;
```

(Where `and_` and `not_` are from the `boost::mpl` namespaces.)

Notice the limited verbosity because you don't have to put with the `::value` boilerplate. Similarly, `result` is lazy, where you can force computing the result with either `result::value` (which would be `true` or `false`) or `result::type` (which would be, well, a type -- the documentation has all the details). Boost.MPL makes it easy not to do that though, so for instance `not_<result>` is enough to invert the logic, even though `not_<result::type>` would also work. A good thing considering that an additoinal `typename` is needed if `result` is dependent.

I do consider Boost.MPL of enormous help in C++03 partly because it emulates variadic templates. For instance, `and_` is not restricted to two arguments. I've shied away from it in C++11 however because in most situations where I used it I now use pack expansion. Things like `and_` are still useful though because it is not possible to expand a pack in arbitrary expressions, e.g. in one that involves the `&&` logical operator. This can only be done with a logical metafunction:

```
// Enforce precondition: every type T must be integral
static_assert( and_<std::is_integral<T>...>::value, "Violation" );
```

I consider [this article](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html) a good read that gives good hints to reduce the verbosity of metacomputations. It focuses on SFINAE as used for generic programming but it is applicable to TMP as well (and SFINAE can be used in TMP as well). The final example is

```
template <typename T,
          EnableIf<is_scalable<T>, is_something_else<T>>...>
T twice(T t) { return 2*t; }
```

which could look like this in C++03, using facilities similar to those provided in Boost:

```
template<typename T>
typename enable_if<
    and_<is_scalable<T>, is_something_else<T>>
    , T
>::type twice(T t) { return 2*t; }
```

A naive C++11 version arguably looks the worst:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_scalable<T>::value && is_something_else<T>::value
    , T
>::type twice(T t) { return 2*t; }
```

I've seen some that advocate moving away from the style of Boost.MPL, which favours types and type-'returning' metafunctions towards using values and `constexpr` functions. This could look like:

```
// EnableIf alias now accepts non-type template parameters
template<typename T
         , EnableIf<is_scalable<T>() && is_something_else<T>()>...>
T twice(T t) { return 2*t; }
```

You'd still need a `constexpr` function to compute e.g. the logical disjunction if `T...` is a pack though: `EnableIf<any(is_foo<T>()...)>`.

Comment: It is possible to combine this advice with `bames53`'s when you do decide to refactor out a metacomputation, e.g. `template<typename T> struct is_foo: and_<is_integral<T>, not_<is_char<T>>>::type {};`. Consider that `T` may again be pack. (It's also possible to make `is_foo` an alias but my experience suggests that it makes compiler diagnostics quite less helpful at this time as the aliases are substituted. YMMV, also with respect to compile-time -- I haven't measured however.)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an integral constant? If you just need a compile-time constant bool then you don't have to wrap the expression.

```
is_integral<T>::value && !is_char<T>::value
```

If you need this expression in several places you can just write you own special type trait.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_integral_and_not_char {
    static const bool value = is_integral<T>::value && !is_char<T>::value;
};

is_integral_and_not_char<T>::value
```

Or if you do want to conform to the UnaryTypeTrait concept then

```
template<typename T>
struct is_integral_and_not_char
  : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_char<T>::value>
{}
```